# Why the css is not affecting in my PHP page?

Tags: php, html, css

I am learning the php and get some difficulties, I am trying to include the php file in header of another file, but the css is not working?

here is my project directory structure
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGYn9.jpg)

and here is my php code...
**blogpage.php**

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>   
    <?php include 'head.php';?>

    <title>Off Canvas Template for Bootstrap</title>

</head>
```

I have included the path in Struts-2/blogpage.php

here is my head.php

```
   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: How do you add CSS in head.php?

Comment: <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: There are slashes missing in your sources. And you have to change "href"  to "src" in yor head.php

Comment: Also adding a "type" attribute would be good.  Like ' type="text/css" '.

Comment: I have included the path in Struts-2/blogpage.php. See the project structure in image

Comment: `css/offcanvas.css`, `css/blog.css`, and `css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css` are all throwing 404s? View the network tab in your developer console. Those should probably be absolute paths.

Comment: yes.. then how to add relative path?

Comment: @PollyTearesa. I have provided with a solution have a try ans share thoughts over to that. If you face any hindrance let me know.

Comment: @PollyTearesa You don't want relative paths, that is what breaks it. You currently are mixing absolute and relative paths. Use absolute and it should work. See TarlanMammadzada's answer.

Comment: @PollyTearesa. I have provide with the standard structure to call the CSS, JS over to the files you call. Hope so this might help you in development.

Answer (score 2):

Is CSS folder located under the head.php?

Try to add slash to all links:

```
   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <link href="/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="/css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You may check, adding the links directly, without including th php. Try in that way to see if the links work.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution One:**

As per your folder structure you have all the `style-sheets` under the `CSS folder` and you are trying to include it in the PHP file which is located `outside` the `CSS folder` and the procedure it that you have to directly point it out to the `CSS folder` to pertain the links to all the files that you provide in `head.php`.

The head.php should look like this so that it will not pertain to any error.

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**Errors:**

1. Your forward slash trailing in the first link will fails since you have added the forward slash over to the `bootstrap.css` and hence that file will not call out in `blogpage.php` page. That is the reason you are not getting css over to the `blogpage.php`.
2. The `type="text/css"` is missing to the stylesheet call in the `head.php` and this may also cause the Error.

And pertaing to that you need to call the `head.php` in the `blogpage.php` as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>   
<?php include ('../head.php'); ?>
<title>Off Canvas Template for Bootstrap</title>
</head>
```

### Best Practice

But you can wrap up all the head.php, footer.php, header.php into the `includes folder` so that it will be a constant under that folder and you can provide up the links without any error.

Since you are calling it inside the `Struts-2` folder your path may fail sometimes and the CSS may result in Error.

> Tips:One the site is loaded up fully you press `CTRL+U` so that your entire code will open up in the new window (View Page Source) and you can check to that whether all the links that you are proving are executing correct in the browser.

**Solution Two:**

You can add up the forward slash over to the CSS folder structure since it will not fails up when you try to add it u over to any of the page that you use. Since all the communication will be done from the root directory on all calls

And your `head.php` will look like

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<link href="/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/css/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Why make the paths all relative? `Struts-2/blogpage.php` is going to load `css/offcanvas.css` as `/Struts-2/css/offcanvas.css`. Per the dir struc that is incorrect, http://i.stack.imgur.com/OGYn9.jpg.

Comment: I have used the standard structure to call the CSS in the project and as per the `Tarlan Mammadzada` code it will work only for this project . I am making it as a general style so that it may be useful for him to develop the code with a perfect structure.

Comment: This will not work as is. The CSS won't load because it isn't where you have specified. `Tarlan Mammadzada` is absolute so it will always start at the server root.

Comment: Why so it will not load up. It will surely load up correct.

Comment: If he is in the `blogpage.php` it will load the `head.php` but he has to provide the link to `head.php` as `include '../head.php'` since the `head.php` is outside of the folder that he has mentioned and that will work perfect with my code.

Comment: never ever this will end up in error if you call the `head.php` correctly in the page where you are working and for the past times am working like this alone. And i have never faced any error too in loading up the CSS.

Comment: If the path (s)he is loading is ` Struts-2/blogpage.php` (as (s)he states) then all included paths will fail with the relative link. The current code would (as it is identical to what you have included) work if (s)he were at the root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125283/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-chris85).